# Insert site name in URL before end of path

Tags: dns, proxy, url-rewriting, cname

I run a white-label hotel booking site that is located at: `http://secure.rezserver.com/home/?refid=4912`.

The name of my company is Expeditioner Hotels, therefore, I would like have the URL display: `ExpeditionerHotels.com/secure.rezserver.com/home/?refid=4912`.

Is this possible to do using CNAME Alias or A Record?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to modification to the configuration of the server hosting your booking site : answering requests on a vhost with host `ExpeditionerHotels.com` and inside URL `/secure.rezserver.com/`

If you cannot do that, you can point `ExpedtionerHotels.com` to your own proxy server (nginx, or squid) that will proxy requests to your booking site.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. I think I need to do the second option. Can I hire you to do this for me? Here's my e-mail if you are interested: matt.stabile@theexpeditioner.com.